# Save On My Domain Class Object Is Not Working.

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a User class which has a List field namely pt. This field is not initialized  when User register his account. But when user goes this controller action :

```
def updatePt() { 
       //performs some action 
       def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)  //find the user 
       user.pt = [] 
       //on certain conditions i put values into user.pt like this 
       user.pt << "E" 
       //at last I save it 
       user.save() 
}
```

But using user/show action via scaffolding I found that pt field is not saved on users object. Where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: Is the pt field part of your mapping ?

Comment: @bunting : Mapping? Can you be clearer? I'm a newbie to Grails world.. Actually `pt` is a `List` in my `User` domain class. I haven't done anything in prior to mapping for `pt`!

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but don't you want to get the User object persisted ? The User object gets persisted, but the pt field doesn't, right ? If so, have you provided a static mapping with  static hasMany = [pt: String] ?

Comment: Ya exactly... the pt field is not getting persisted! Actually as i mentioned in my question, the User have already been created but at that time pt field not been used or initialized. So in this controller action, I need to update my user with his/her new pt value.

Comment: @bunting: and I havent done any mapping related stuff so far. I just gave `List pt` in my `User` domain class.

Comment: @bunting: your answer was right! why do you delete your answer by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a static mapping in the Users domain class so that Grails knows the field must be persisted:

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [pt: String]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible because of validation error. Try with

```
if (!user.save()) {
   log.error('User not saved')
   user.errors.each {
       log.error('User error: $it')
   }
}
```

PS or you can use `println` instead of `log.error`

Comment: I have already used these techniques, I guess its not because of validation errors!

Comment: I get `error grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors` this when I use this technique..